# Install wheel file on off-line machine which has different processor

Tags: python-3.x, pip

I have a wheel file for ARM64 based platform which should be installed by `pip3 install MyWheelfile.whl` on an **offline computer**.

How can I download all the required dependencies to an **online** computer which is x86-64 platform?

Comment: Do you know that you can just download files manually from pypi.org?

Comment: @FlyingTeller, Well, I am looking for an automatic way.....

Comment: @FlyingTeller You hardly could download wheels for ARM64 from PyPI. From PiWheels, may be…

Comment: @BennyK Raspberry Pi? Try `pip download --index-url=https://www.piwheels.org/simple`

Comment: @phd - No, it's NVIDIA XAVIER AGX and offline....... a true nightmare....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the --platform flag with pip download to get the desired version of the wheel. You probably can't get the ARM wheels from PyPi (I haven't done enough with ARM myself to be sure), but piwheels should have them.

This worked for me to get numpy:

```
pip download --index-url=https://www.piwheels.org/simple --platform linux_armv7l --no-deps numpy
```

You can of course combine this with a requirements.txt file to get all of your packages at once if you want

```
pip download --index-url=https://www.piwheels.org/simple --platform linux_armv7l --no-deps -r requirements.txt
```

In requirements.txt (example):

```
pandas==1.0.1
numpy>=1.18.1
```

I'm not sure exactly what version you need, but you can see available versions at piwheels (e.g. for numpy go to https://www.piwheels.org/simple/numpy/)