# Using GRPC python without internet access and pip install for custom Linux distro

Tags: python, pip, grpc-python

I need to run a GRPC server on a custom Linux distro, which has no access to internet or python pip. Can anyone please provide some guidance how I can generate the cygrpc.cp37-win_amd64 file specific to the platform**[32bit custom Linux with Python 3.7]**? I have noted that if I copy the grpc folder, the only error that comes up is that GRPC **fails to import cygrpc**

Comment: We can not provide guidance on Stack Overflow. You have to give all relevant details and ask one specific question.

Comment: when we do pip install grpcio, inside **grpc\_cython** folder, cygrpc.cp37-win_amd64 file is created. I need to generate the same file manually for the aforementioned Linux distro. My question is how can I generate this file: cygrpc.cp37-win_amd64 but for LINUX i.e. compile locally.

Comment: Is pip installed on your distro and just can't reach out to the internet? If so you can just download the specific wheels you need and copy them over. If you don't have pip at all, you might still be able to use this method, but then extract the WHL files and manually runt the setup.py files for each. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60182080/install-wheel-file-on-off-line-machine-which-has-different-processor/60192557#60192557

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I found for this problem is to use a Docker container with 32bit Linux(for e.g. RHEL) image and install gRPC in this container. After installation the platform specific **cygrpc.cp..** file is generated inside **_cython** folder in **grpc** folder. Then it can be used wherever you need it.